# Optimal way to join 30 billions with 3 billions in spark

Tags: apache-spark, optimization

I have two hive tables stored in parquet.

Table1 (30 billions records) schema:

key1: lots of unique values

key2: sometimes equal to key1, but sometimes key1 can have multiple key2

key3: around 1000 unique values

col1: some value to update

col2: 7 unique values, table partitioned by this column. 90% of records are in one partition, can be calculated from key3

Table2 (3 billions records) schema:

key1: lots of unique values

key2: sometimes equal to key1, but sometimes key1 can have multiple key2

key3: around 1000 unique values

col1: some value to update

col2: 7 unique values (same history as in table1, but table2 not partitioned by this column)

partition_col: data + hour

What I need is to df(table1).join(df(table2), Seq(key1,key2,key3), "full") and update col1 if it exists in tab1 or add new record it it's not exists.
This looks like usual broadcast case, but table2 is too big to be broadcasted (more than 10G).

What I've tried:

1. Different parameters for spark.sql.shuffle.partitions
2. Shuffle hash join
3. In upstream job partition tables by key3 (extra time in upstream job to write partitioned data is > that time profit on join)
4. Different size of executors: for example 30 x 8 cores x 64G.

Main issue is sortMergeJoin step, and options above didn't give any noticeable improvement. Increasing resources not the case (I have 60 executors x 4 cores x 32G memory per executor).

I want to understand if it can be done better on code level, mb add some parameters I'm missing or even change logic how to update records in bigger table.

At spark plan it's read parquet.

Comment: #1 - Could you share the stats from join stage? Are there any skewness, memory/disk spills, is task duration evenly distributed, etc. etc. #2 - Have you considered splitting small table into 10+ "sections" (using a filter on key fields) so that each part can be broadcasted and joined with large table individually, and then union the results? Will take extra toll on I/O but could be still faster.

Comment: Did you notice few tasks struggling?

Comment: No spills. Read is min 174mb, max 175mb. No skew. Duration 75th percentile 45s, max 4.9 min. Overall duration 30 mins. Size of "small" table is 80gb, big is 1600gb. Splitting to sections can be tricky I think... But will try. I think in this case it should be pieces 1-2 gb, correct? It'll be 40 pieces for broadcast, each is 2gb, sounds dangerous :)

Comment: No struggling for tasks. I'm joining by unique key.

Comment: Yeah, 40+ broadcast pieces might be too much and may not give any benefit... I didnt realize that "more than 10G" could mean 80gb :)) I guess the only way to get better performance would be to increase parallelism, since right now 60 x 4 = 240 task slots and 1600gb / 200mb = 8000 tasks -> 8000 / 240 = 33 task waves which kind of what you're seeing with average task less than a minute.

Comment: In this case increase parallelism = increase executors / cores? I have spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = 10000